# Qt - add a hyperlink to a dialog

Tags: c++, qt, hyperlink

Is there a way to add a clickable hyperlink in a Qt Dialog? I.e. it should look like a hyperlink (blue text), and when you click on it, it should open the hyperlink in the browser. Something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `QLabel::setOpenExternalLinks(bool)`, and set text on label `<a href="yourlink">link text</a>`.

Comment: there is an error: Error 1 error C2039: 'setOpenExternalLinks' : is not a member of 'QLabel'

Comment: @Narek: setOpenExternalLinks was introduced in Qt 4.2. What version are you using?

Comment: oops I have been using 4.1.3 Thanks.

Comment: If you want the link's action to do something other than opening a link, connect to the QLabel's `linkActivated` signal, which has one parameter, the href.