# Qt: how can I make hyperlink in qpushbutton?

Tags: c++, qt, hyperlink

hi I'm trying to make hyperlink in a QPushbutton.

I searched for information that mights help and I found this:
[Qt - add a hyperlink to a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465413/qt-add-a-hyperlink-to-a-dialog)

this told me how can I use hyperlink at a dialog(or mainwindow.)

However, what I want to is to use hyperlink *in the QMessagebox when appears after clicking QPushbutton.*

I searched that if I can use qlabel in qmessagebox but I couldn't find any information..

How can I do this?

(Any other way I can apply to make hyperlink by clicking a second button is fine. What I'm trying to do is 1st. click a button and my program will get an url information. 2nd. clicking a second button and it will activate my url)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is *clicking a second button and it will activate my url* then you can use [QDesktopServices::openUrl()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl) to open a URL. It automatically uses the application the user has configured, i.e. the browser or mail programm depending on the type of URL you give it.

Comment: I think it was the perfect answer I was looking for! That was the exact function I tired to use but I didn't know about QDesktopServices. I'm working with it and (though I think my Qurl is not working - I checked and it's invalid so I'll work on it) it opens my internet! Thanks a lot